# User-thread implementation on a web server: how does a finite-state machine handle interrupts to avoid race conditions

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, state-machine

I was studying processes and threads in a book called The 4th Edition of Modern Operating System by Andrew Tanenbaum and Herbert Bos. The book on page 102 stated that a single thread process program gave up its performance for simplicity. On the other hand, finite-state machines provided parallel processing but had to process interruptions.

As an alternative to the blocking method, I had a question about the finite-state machine processing interrupt.

I thought the blocking method was not only to simplify programming but also to avoid race conditions when threads run concurrently.

I would like to ask about how race conditions are handled in such a case as a finite-state machine.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't allow interrupt handlers to fire events directly.  The handler could queue up events /data in a queue and signal a semaphore for each one.  The thread that runs the state machine waits on the semaphore, dequeues the events and runs the state machine.  Any events from other threads could be queued up in a similar manner, the FSM thread polling each queue every time the semaphore is signaled.

Comment: Understood! Thank you for the explanation. :D